# Typescript 2.0 unknown compiler error

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, inversifyjs

I'm getting this error

```
    Unknown compiler option 'lib'. (5023)
    Unknown compiler option 'types'. (5023)
```

I removed typescript from node_module didn't work
used npm uninstall typescript and npm install -g typescript didn't work again
used npm uninstall -g typescript npm install -g typescript didn't work again

any idea?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Can you you post an answer or flag the one of the answers below as valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the latest version of [TypeScript](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) and reloading your solution.

*After editing .proj file, the tsConfig.json and a few other hopeless fixes, I simply installed Typescript (which was 2.5.2), opened the solution, and the 'Unknown Compiler Option' build errors disappeared.*

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked:

- Whatever file is launching typescript (e.g. the scripts tag of package.json)
- The tsconfig.json file?

It sounds to me like one of them may be set up incorrectly.  Is that possible?

Comment: "scripts": {
         "start": "ts-node index.ts",
         "postinstall": "typings install"
          }

and tsconfig is:
        {
        "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",

         "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
         "types": ["reflect-metadata"],
         "module": "commonjs",
          "moduleResolution": "node",
          "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
         "outDir": "build"
         },
         "exclude": [
         "node_modules"
         ]
         }

Comment: OK, now do you see the two keys "lib" and "types" that the compiler is complaining about?  You need to go research the typescript compiler options, google tsconfig etc.  Doesn't appear to me like they're supported.

Comment: Hi guys these options are supported by TS >= 2.0 I have added a note in the installation docs to highlight this requirement https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/README.md#installation

Answer (score 1):

I have added the following to the [InversifyJS docs](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/README.md#installation):

> **Important!** InversifyJS requires TypeScript >= 2.0 and the `experimentalDecorators`, `emitDecoratorMetadata`, `types` and `lib` 
>   compilation options in your `tsconfig.json` file.

The options `types` and `lib` are only supported by TypeScript >= 2.0.

Comment: yes I noticed that in the doc and I have typescript >2.0 but still i'm getting that error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error code using Webstorm. It turns out that I wasn't using the latest version of Webstorm, and the version I was using, used Typescript 1.8... After installing the latest Webstorm, no more issue.